# Is there anything wrong with this html?

Tags: html

This html comes from an email, is there anything wrong with it? Would you use the breaks and span? Many thanks. Edit: Marking this post as -1 isn't very kind. Yes, I am an html noob, but I've just spent two hours trying to figure out whether there is something wrong with it.

```html
<span style="font-size:12px; color:#XXXXXX;">
  <br />
  <br />
  Hi Joe,
  <br />
  <br />
    You have requested to withdraw XXXX. You can expect XXXX.
  <br />
  <br />
    <a href="https://XXXX.com" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold; color:#2XXXXX; font-size:12px;">View XXXX</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    If you did not carry out this transaction... <a href="mailto:contactus@XXXX.com">contactus@XXXX.com</a><br />
    <br />
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with it as far as I can tell. Breaks are good because every email client reads it. When you're dealing with margins, some would have issues. Padding and tables is usually the best choice, though. But for only text, this would be fine.